# Body background issue

Tags: css, wordpress, background

My website is at http://filmblurb.org. As you can see, I did a CSS trick with the `min-height` tag to make the page-container infinitely scroll vertically when the window is zoomed out. The problem is that the gray from the background (from the `body` tag) overlaps the white background in the page-container when you first load the site. Anybody know why's it doing that and how I can go about trying to fix it so that the gray always stays in the background? I tried everything to fix this, but I can't figure out the problem.

Thank you for your help in advance. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing your problem, but I would think this would work:

```
html {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
background-color: gray;
background-attachment: fixed; /* may be overkill */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I used that code, it made my `html` tag not appear correctly when viewing the code in Chrome. Why is that? The `html` tag doesn't extend all the way to the bottom edge of the window when I inspected it. But anyway, I think the delay for my little overlapping problem might have something to do with the page speed because it doesn't do that when I take the ad off.

Comment: @jtarr523 Well that would make sense why I'm not seeing your problem... I'm using an ad blocking extension. I'm going to look at your code again, though.

Answer (score 0):

On line 59 in your style.css,
change

```
  html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    }
```

to

```
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But when I do that, my `html` and `body` tags don't extend all the way down to the bottom when the code is viewed in Chrome (when you inspect the element obviously). Any reason for that?

Comment: try and add an !important tag to the element.. It's strange that that doesn't work, because it should. 
 
html, body {
    height: 100% !important;
    }

It does extend to the bottom when I try it, and yes it's in chrome inspect element,  but also in Firebug for Firefox.. Did you replace an existing code in your css? 

Try and make a new element at the bottom of your style.css 
(just paste the code I gave you in this comment)

Comment: I took a screen shot of the css when it works in Chrome Inspect Element

http://i48.tinypic.com/vrrkpe.png

And

http://i45.tinypic.com/b7gf0m.png

Comment: The container in fact extends to the bottom of the window, but for some reason even when the height is 100% for both the body and tag, those two elements go about halfway down the page and then stop. When I'm profiling those elements in Google Inspect Element that is.

Comment: From what I understood your problem was, the site works now? 
The white bg extends now all the way to the bottom, and the grey is behind it. 
The html and body tag stretch to the bottom when zooming out.. 
Can you specify what goes only half way on the page because I don't see it? Except for the page-feed of course, that will extend with more content?

Comment: I've also taken screenshots of what I'm seeing to give you a better idea. Here they are [link]http://i917.photobucket.com/albums/ad16/jtarr523/Bodyprofilingchrome.jpg (for the body) and [link]http://i917.photobucket.com/albums/ad16/jtarr523/HTMLprofilechrome.jpg (for the HTML)...Both are not extending to the bottom.

Comment: That is just strange, since it does for me, both on Mac, PC, Firefox and Chrome.. I did exactly what you did in your screenshots, and it expands to the bottom each time.. 
The "height:100% !important" makes it. 
Have you tried to refresh your cache and all web history and checked if that works?

Comment: I just did this. And that didn't seem to work. That's weird that we're seeing two different things. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Oh, well!
I have looked at it again and again and it still looks stable and it works here.. sorry I cant help more than so.. strange indeed!

Anyway, may I suggest a margin-right: 20px on your .factbox? It gives the main content more room to breath.
Just a friendly advice. 

Good luck!  
.factbox {
float: left;
width: 180px;
border-top: 5px solid 
#D00000;
margin-right: 20px;
}

Comment: Yep I'm currently working on coding that div. Thanks for the heads up though.